# Sending JSON data from IONIC to Twilio PHP API

Tags: php, json, ionic-framework, sms, twilio

Trying to send JSON data from my IONIC app to the Twilio PHP API located on my server.

**IONIC APP**: 
I want to send an SMS to whatever mobile number is entered in the form's input (mobile) when the submit button(sendSMS) is clicked:

```
sendSMS() {
this.submitAttempt = true;

  if(this.formGroup.valid){ 
      var link = 'https://mywebsite.com/send-sms.php';
      var myData = JSON.stringify({mobile: this.formGroup.controls[ 'mobile' ].value});

       this.http.post(link, myData)
      .subscribe(data => {
      this.data.response = data["_body"];
      });    
  }
```

**PHP handling twilio request**: 
I don't know what I've missed or done wrong in the code below...I want to send an SMS to the JSON data (mobile input value) received from the IONIC app:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");

$account_sid = "mysid";
$auth_token = "mytoken";
$twilio_phone_number = "mymobile";

$request = json_decode($postdata);
$mobile = $request->mobile;

$client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);

$client->messages->create(
   $mobile,
    array(
        "from" => $twilio_phone_number,
        "body" => "hello"
    )
);
```

Comment: I'd love to help but it's hard to diagnose at the moment. What error are you getting? And at what stage of the process do you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was a HTTP issue. For anyone else who is trying to use Ionic with a Twilio PHP script on their server:

```
require_once 'vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/autoload.php'; 
use Twilio\Rest\Client;


if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    
}


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        
        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

    exit(0);
}$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");if (isset($postdata)) {

    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $userMobile = $request->mobile;

if ($userMobile != "") {
    echo "Server returns: " . $userMobile;           


$account_sid = 'your-twilio-account-sid'; 
$auth_token = 'your-twilio-authtoken'; 
$client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token); 

$client->messages->create(
        $userMobile,
        array(
            'From' => "YOUR TWILIO NUMBER",  
            'Body' => "MESSAGE YOU WANT TO SEND",   
        )
    );

echo "Sent message!";

} else {
    echo "Could not send SMS";
}   }
```